# How can i make that when a poll reaches por example 5 votes send the message to another channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a poll, but all the ones I see have a limit of time created with asyncio, but I want to make that when the a poll reaches 5 reaction of the emoji ✅ instead of having a limit of time, send the message to another channel, I already have the poll itself done

```
@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='poll', description='Create a poll')
@commands.has_role(Staff_role)
async def poll(self, ctx, message):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f'Poll por {ctx.author}', description=f'{message}',color=embed_color)
    msg=await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    emoji = '✅'
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
    emoji = ''
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

How can I check if a embed of a specific channel have 5 reactions of a specific emoji send the message that got that 5 reactions to another channel?

Comment: You could use the `wait_for` feature of discord.py (in a loop) until it reaches 5 reactions, or simply use the even `on_raw_reaction_add` or `on_reaction_add`, and then check the id of the message that the emoji was added on with the message you've sent with the emojis on.

Comment: @Infinity I've done this simple code to test it `@commands.Cog.listener() async def on_reaction_add(self,reaction, user): if reaction.count == 2 and reaction.emoji == "✅": await reaction.message.delete()`  but how could I get the content of the embed instead of deleteing it?

Comment: swap `await reaction.message.delete()` to `messageContent = reaction.message.content`.
Just be aware that `on_reaction_add` only works for cached messages (received while the bot has been online in the current session). If you want to apply this that have not been cached, you need to use `on_raw_reaction_add`

Comment: @Infinity Now i was trying to send the message like this `channel = bot.get_channel(id_channel_ticket_logs)
            await channel.send(messageContent)` and i got an error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'** how could i send it?

Comment: Your channel ID is invalid which is why you get an error when trying to post to it. Make sure the channel ID: is an integer, valid, and that the bot can access the channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it, but you must change if if your bot turns off anytime, if it's always on this code should work:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_reaction_add(self,reaction, user):
    if reaction.count == 2 and reaction.emoji == "✅":
        await reaction.message.reply(f"Votacion Aceptada")
    elif reaction.count == 2 and reaction.emoji == "❌":
        await reaction.message.delete()
```

It just check how many reacctions has the message of X emoji, and if it equals to something, it does that thing, I recomend putting `==` instead of `>`or `>=`
because everytime someone votes it will resend the message